# how to model if else statement in mixed integer program

Tags: mathematical-modeling, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to model a if-then condition for a MIP. The MIP looks like

Maximize $\sum\limits_i H_i - C$

s.t. $\sum\limits_j x_{ij} \le D_i$ and $\sum\limits_i x_{ij} \le S_i$,
where $H_i = 1$ if $\sum\limits_j x_{ij} = D_i$, and $0$ otherwise; 
$C = \sum\limits_{i,j}$ if $x_{ij} \gt 0$ then $1$, $0$ otherwise.

$x_{ij}$ is integer.

I know how to model a simple if-then condition in an MIP. But not able to model this one.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to do this hinges on whether $x$ is integer-valued or not. For non-integer $x$,you will have to compromise a bit. I have details posted at [Flagging a Specific Variable Value](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2015/02/flagging-specific-variable-value.html).

Comment: Thanks @prubin. x is integer. I just edited the question to reflect this. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @prubin https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234098/how-to-model-iff-statements-in-milp is answer known to you?